# Emacs C-c } command and parentheses-match checking

Tags: emacs, emacs23, parentheses

I am working in Emacs 23, editing LaTeX via AUCTeX. I noticed in emacs that when I press `C-c }`, I receive the minibuffer message

> Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 16026, 16440

Question 1. What exactly is this command doing?

Question(s) 2. More generally, how can I determine what I a given macro is doing? Is there, for example, a universal command that request the keyboard shortcut as an input and outputs a description of the command to which that shortcut is bound? Is there a list of all active keyboard shortcuts?

Question 3. How can I find my unmatched parentheses? The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323034/finding-unbalanced-braces-and-parentheses) recommends the command `M-x check-parens`, but it availed me nothing, not even a minibuffer message.

Comment: check-parens works for me when I'm using AucTex. Maybe something in your config is interfering - what happens when you start emacs as `emacs -Q`? You'll probably have to manually load AucTex after you do this, but don't run any other code from your .emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to 1 and 2 is to do `C-h k C-c }` and see what the help buffer tells you. This is one of the features that allows us to call Emacs a self-documenting editor. Don't forget that you can follow the links in the help buffer to both the source code where this function is implemented and to other documentation.

You may also want to use `C-h m` to see all the key bindings added by the major and minor modes that are currently enabled and `C-h ?` to see what other interesting help functions there are.

I've never used `check-parens` specifically, but it does work in my current buffer, which is javascript. I see from its documentation (`C-h f check-parens`) that it relies on the current syntax table, so perhaps for TeX the syntax table doesn't contain enough information for `check-syntax` to find the error.